# How to split a paragraph in form of array using some input pattern by using regex and split() function..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, search

I want to search keywords from a given paragraph and split that paragraph in form of array, when that input keywords encounters in that paragraph. Search should be in case insensitive form.

```
toFindString = "Stable NDA product";

paragraph = "NDA sampled and analyzed your “Sandhills Select Horse Feed found stable monensin at 4.2 parts per million or 4 grams/ton standard and reproductive product."
```

Each keyword from given pattern **toFindString** should be search individually.

I am doing like this:

```
var splitedArray = paragraph.split(new RegExp(`(${toFindString .join("|")})`, "gi"));
```

Output i'm getting is:

```
splitedArray =  ["NDA" , "sampled and analyzed your “Sandhills Select Horse Feed found stable", "monensin at 4.2 parts per million or 4 grams/ton sta", "nda", "rd and re", "product", "ive", "product" ]
```

But i want result like this:

```
splitedArray = ["NDA" , "sampled and analyzed your “Sandhills Select Horse Feed found", "stable", "monensin at 4.2 parts per million or 4 grams/ton standard and reproductive", "product" ]
```

The code i'm using, It does not search and splits at "Stable", because in paragraph it is "stable". And it searchs and splits NDA from standard as 'nda' is present in word standard, same is happening for "**product**" keyword and it is present in re**product**ive.

I want output as only as input keyword as a whole, and it should search both case uppercase and lowercase as well, but as a whole keyword like nda or NDA, not from in between a word, like it is doing in case of **NDA** and **product** from sta**nda**rd and re**product**ive.

```js
let toFindString = "Stable NDA product";
let paragraph = "NDA sampled and analyzed your “Sandhills Select Horse Feed found stable monensin at 4.2 parts per million or 4 grams/ton standard and reproductive product.";
var splitedArray = paragraph.split(new RegExp(`(${toFindString .join("|")})`, "gi"));
console.log(splitedArray);
```

Comment: There’s no way you’re getting that output with `toFindString .join("|")` if `toFindString = "Stable NDA product"`. Please show actual value.

Comment: I am a little confused sorry. You want to search a string for another string and for each match, split it?

Comment: Please provide an accurate problem statement and code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is

1. Use `split()` and keep the delimiter.

   - put parenthesis around the delimiter, i.e. `(Stable|NDA|product)`
2. Match whole word (not partial match)

   - put `\b` in regexp to match word boundary, i.e. `\b(Stable|NDA|product)\b`

Put together, please see working demo below

```js
let toFindString = "Stable NDA product";

let paragraph = "NDA sampled and analyzed your “Sandhills Select Horse Feed found stable monensin at 4.2 parts per million or 4 grams/ton standard and reproductive product.";

// Combining point 1 & 2 from explanation above
let regex = "\\b(" + toFindString.split` `.join`|` + ")\\b";

console.log("RegExp used is", regex);

let splitedArray = paragraph.split(new RegExp(regex, "i"))
   .map(x => x.trim())
   .filter(x => x);

console.log(splitedArray);
```

Comment: Nice - perhaps `trim()`?

Comment: Yes, `trim()` will be good, I'll update the answer, but I'm leaving the trailing `.` for OP to deal with.

Comment: You can put `\b` outside the parentheses, since it’s zero-width. Makes the inside simpler, as in `new RegExp("\\b(" + keywords.join("|") + ")\\b", "i")` (the `g` flag also making no difference in `split`).

Comment: updated, thanks @Ry-

Comment: thnks much, this is working for me. :-)